# How can I choose FRA without HHN on kiwi.com?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, planning, flight-search-engines, frankfurt

I'm a big fan of the flight search engine [kiwi.com](https://www.kiwi.com/us/) but there is one feature of it that annoys me over and over.

When I specify as departure airport FRA (Frankfurt International Airport), I am getting suggestions also from HHN ("Frankfurt" Hahn, a cumbersome 2h bus ride from Frankfurt city center and served mainly by Ryanair).

How can I turn this off? I am not selecting Frankfurt (the city), where this might be justified. This feature/bug does not exist for say Rome: when I select FCO, I am not getting any flights out of CIA just as expected.

[image]

Comment: Funny thing: when I try that same search, it also offers me flights from cologne!

Comment: Kiwi seems to favor price over all other things. Plenty of booking engines can find you that 11-hour CDG-BKK flight running 1229++ USD. Kiwi says, well that's boring, wouldn't you rather go ORY-ARN-DXB-COK-DMK or BVA-BGY-KBP-IKA-BKK? It'll take 50 hours but cost you a third as much. Ah, to be a backpacker again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a bit of a roundabout way of doing this:

- Instead of searching by airport, do a 'radius search'
  [image: radius search]
- Click somewhere near Frankfurt International on the map. It will give you a ridiculously big radius including half of Germany. If you scroll to the edge of the radius, it has handles to resize the radius. Use those to make the radius small enough to only include FRA but not HHN.
  [image: Small radius including only FRA]
- There you go, your results will only include results from FRA.
  [image: Results]

It's not very intuitive. If you click directly on FRA on the map when using the radius tool, it will change back to searching for FRA instead (including HHN). So you have to click somewhere close to it instead.

Comment: Every Kiwi answer gets this comment: check https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/134484/4188 before using their guarantee.