# Transit visa for Indians in Thailand

Tags: visas, transit-visas, thailand

I am flying from Hanoi to Bengaluru via Chiang Mai and DMK Bangkok. I am an Indian national. Do I need to have a transit visa for Thailand?

Answer (score 1):

You need a visa, because you will have to cross Thai immigration to enter at Chiang Mai and take the domestic flight to Bangkok.

You can get a visa on arrival for a stay of up to 15 days, but to ensure that you don't have any problems at the airline and to go faster through immigration, I recommend you get an e-visa in advance from the [official Thai e-visa web site](http://en.evisathailand.com/).

Comment: I have a layover of 1.15 hours at Chiang Mie. Would that be enough to complete immigration?

Comment: Did you book these flights separately?

Comment: I have booked my flight from  kiwi.com and following is the initianary :  (15.20 )Hanoi to (16.55 )Chiang Mie by Thai airasia  . (18.10) Chiang Mie to (19.15) DMK by NOK.(20.55 ) DMK to Bengaluru by Thai airasia

Comment: @AccAditya Please see [What does the “Kiwi.com Guarantee” cover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/134484/3221). Then check your booking. If it says "Connection protected by the carrier" then you do not need to worry about the connection time. If it says "Connection protected by the Kiwi.com Guarantee" then if you miss the connecting flight you will have to get help from Kiwi.com instead of the airline, and many people have had bad experiences with this. It might be enough time, if immigration goes very quickly, but I would not risk it for my own personal flight.

Comment: Thanks Michael,it's indeed Kiwi.com gaurentee.I guess it would be less risky to book a direct flight from Hanoi to Bangkok  with 8 hours of layover .In this case also I would require transit visa?

Comment: @AccAditya You even then still need a visa because you have to cross immigration in Thaialnd if you fly on low cost carriers such as VietJet, Jetstar, etc. So everything above about the visa still applies.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. I have booked Thai airasia flights and since I have around 8 hours I would check if I need to cross transit in Bangkok and if required I can buy Visa on Arrival there.

Comment: @AccAditya If you are on Thai Airasia for both flights, in and out of Bangkok, then you should be able to stay in the international area and not need a visa.

Comment: Hi Michael the issue is that I have different booking numbers due to which I may need to do immigration process again which may require visa. Any thought on this?

Comment: @AccAditya I think the visa is relatively cheap and easy to get.

Comment: I checked the documents which requires hotel booking details which I don't have,need to check with any consultant