# Can I transit through GRU (São Paulo) airport without visa, if have single ticket with no check-in baggage?

Tags: transit-visas, brazil, bangladeshi-citizens, gru

I am traveling from Addis Ababa to Paramaribo (Suriname) next month. I booked ticket from kiwi.com from Addis Ababa to Suriname (Single booking number) with Turkish airlines from Addis Ababa to São Paulo (GRU) and São Paulo to Suriname with GOL airlines.

1. Can I get my boarding pass for my whole trip from Turkish airlines as they have interline agreement with GOL airlines. I already emailed to Turkish airlines but no response yet.
2. kiwi.com says: they don't support online check-in for this route. So, How can I collect my boarding pass if Turkish airlines don't provide any.

I have no check-in baggage and 3 hours layover at GRU airport.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no direct flight between GRU and PMB. This could very well mean you have an internal flight from GRU to somewhere else, before flying into Suriname. That could then mean you have to enter Brazil at GRU to get a local flight.

Comment: Do you know your itinerary between GRU and PMB?

Comment: Does your booking say "connection guaranteed by Kiwi" or "connection guaranteed by the airlines" ?

Comment: There are no direct flights between GRU and PBM. You need to give us more detail but chances are high you need proper documentation to enter Brasil.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no direct flight. GRU to Belem to PBM with GOL airlines.

Comment: kiwi says "The Kiwi.com Guarantee protects you from cancellations, delays and rescheduling" -

Comment: As to visas: I don't think it matters. Either the OP will pass Brazilian immigration in GRU, or after transit at GRU, will fly to BEL and pass Brazilian immigration there. In either case, the OP will have to be admissible into Brazil. Having whatever docs might be required for an airside transit at GRU will be subsumed by having the proper docs to enter Brazil. As to boarding passes: if the OP can't get a boarding pass for the second flight in Addis or Istanbul, one can be obtained in Sao Paolo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I don't need visa to pass Brazilian Immigration and I can get boarding pass at Sao Paolo. Turkish airlines replied as: "Based on your message; we would like to inform you that you can only complete your check in process for Turkish Airlines flights through our official channels or at the check in counter. It is possible to make check in for any other Airlines through our official channels.Kindly submitted for your information"
 So I can get my boarding pass either from Turkish airlines at addis ababa or at GRU, Brazil. So, no need transit visa. Am I right?? Thanks

Comment: @zaman What happened in the end?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your listed questions:

1. It will depend on whether kiwi booked the actual flights unter a single PNR. It is not neccessarily the case that they will, even with airlines with interline agreements, they can still buy different tickets under different PNRs for you, as this may or may not make the whole booking cheaper. You will have to wait for the answer by Turkish to get clear facts here, or you can look through all documents provided by kiwi to see if there are different PNRs in there (e-ticket, receipt, ...). AFAIR, the kiwi booking as a whole may also have another PNR, if they booked single flights with different PNRs.
2. That means for kiwi.com, that they will not check you in automatically and you have to do it yourself with the airline - Turkish will in fact provide a boarding pass, but you have to request it yourself using your PNR, subject to Turkish's policy.

For us to be able to answer your actual question, whether you'll be able to actually travel with this booking, we need more information as others have stated in the comments:

1. Your citizenship
   Bangladesh
2. Your complete itinerary
   ADD → IST → GRU with Turkish airlines and GRU → BELEM → PBM with GoL Airlines
3. Were all your flights booked on a single PNR by kiwi?
4. Does your booking say "connection protected by kiwi/the airline(s)"?

Probably doesn't help you with the exact question, but it is a good read anyway in case of problems along the way: [Q: What does the “Kiwi.com Guarantee” cover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134484/what-does-the-kiwi-com-guarantee-cover)

---

**You will probably need a visa.**

Since your booking is split over your flights, it can be argued that it TWOV does not apply to you. You do have all the flights on one e-ticket, but I don't know if that's sufficient. But what's worse, your flight GRU - Belem is a Brazil domestic flight. It is very likely that TWOV doesn't apply to domestic connections at all. This might also mean that a "airport transit visa" - if such exists in Brazil - isn't sufficient either and you have to get a full visitor visa; this would be the case in Germany for example.

---

Timatic says:

Brazil - Transit Visa

Visa required.
Transiting without a visa is possible for:

Passengers with a connecting flight booked on the same ticket in transit.

This TWOV facility does not apply at Curitiba (CWB), Florianopolis (FLN), Porto Alegre (POA), Porto Seguro (BPS) or Salvador (SSA).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My citizenship is: Bangladesh. I will travel from ADD TO IST TO GRU with Turkish airlines and GRU TO BELEM TO PBM with GoL Airlines. Yes  booking say "connection protected by kiwi.

Comment: Single PNR or several PNRs?

Comment: You can check if they booked under several PNRs by opening your e-Ticket. Each flight will show a PNR in the top right corner of the page it's listed on. If all the PNRs are the same, then it's a genuine single PNR booking.

Comment: No it is not single PNR.

Comment: added to answer