# Transiting through KLIA2 on separate tickets without checked baggage

Tags: transit, check-in

I'm a Malaysian citizen and I will fly from Penang (PEN) to Singapore (SIN) and transit through KLIA2. I have bought separate tickets from Penang to KLIA2 (7th January 2022 0755-0900) and KLIA2 to Singapore (7th January 2022 1005-1105) from the same airlines (AirAsia). I will also be entering Singapore through Vaccinated Travel Lane (VTL).

I have no checked baggage on both flights, so do I need to go to the AirAsia check-in counter at the departure hall to have my documents checked and check-in, or I can do the same at the transit counters in the transfer hall? Due to the extremely tight layover time, I would really hope that I can settle pre-flight administrative stuff at the transit counters.

I have seen some [sources](https://www.tripadvisor.com.my/ShowTopic-g298570-i7008-k7590084-o40-Airasia_transit_in_KLIA2-Kuala_Lumpur_Wilayah_Persekutuan.html) saying that usually the staff at KLIA2 will allow me to transit directly but that is against the regulations. I am not sure if anything changes due to current restrictions.

Remark: I have attempted to buy a flight ticket from Penang to Singapore, transiting at KLIA2, under the same booking number. However, it is not available in the system for some reasons. Also, the flight from Penang to KLIA2 was rescheduled from an earlier time, hence the tight layover.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the information contained in the accepted answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer) might useful to you.