# Riyadh Airport: Terminal 4 to 2

Tags: connecting-flights, airport-terminals, self-transfer, ruh

I have a self transfer flight coming up in a couple of days.

SV374 arriving at T4 in RUH and then 2h later, AI922 departing from T2

Is it possible to go from T4 to T2 while staying within the VISA free transit zone?

Comment: Do you have any checked luggage? Are you sure you can check-in for your second flight without going to a check-in desk? Any of those would require you to go through passport control. Also 2 hours seems extremely risky for a self-transfer, and it's not even guaranteed that Saudia will even let you board the first flight if you can't enter Saudi Arabia (have a visa or are visa-exempt).

Comment: May be relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer/171372#171372

Comment: Vighnesh, did you manage to get from T4 to T2 without visa?

Comment: Yes I did but it was definitely an irregular case. I had to ask an airport agent and they arranged a bus solely for me to drive me over. It’s not possible to walk - they are not connected on the inside without getting past security checkpoints.

Comment: Wasn’t too bad, but a bit anxiety provoking for sure

Answer (score 2):

I called RUH and the agent there said that I could transfer from T4 to T2 without requiring a VISA.

Would still love to hear from someone who has actually been inside RUH!

Comment: It would perhaps be better to collect together all your answers into one by editing the first one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the information desk here at the airport, it is not possible to go from terminal 4 to 2 or 1. It is only possible to move between terminal 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment, it is possible to go from T4 to T2 without visa.

> I called RUH and the agent there said that I could transfer from T4 to
> T2 without requiring a VISA.