# Riyadh Airport Terminal 3 to 2: Do I have to go through immigration process and come back again for checkin? Are 3 hours good for it?

Tags: transit, saudi-arabia, self-transfer, ruh

I have international flight from Flynas landing at Riyadh around 21:00 at terminal 3.
My next flight is at 00:30 from terminal 2, different airline.

I have a question. Do I have to go through immigration process and come back again for checkin? Are 3 hours good for it? Or I can go to terminal 2 from terminal 3 directly without any immigration process or visa?

Please note, I'll checkin online for my next flight that I have to catch. And I won't have any checkin luggage. I will only have 1 hand bag. Plz assist me if I need to go through immigration or not? How long will it take to reach T2 from T3. Are 3 hours good enough for it?

Both are different tickets, booked separately. I'm Pakistani. I have KSA multiple entry visit visa already. I only have to go to T2 from T3 to catch next flight. With Only hand bag.

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket or were they booked separately? What is your citizenship? What visas or residence permits do you hold (e.g. Schengen, UK, US...)? See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer/171372#171372 especially the "Can the first airline refuse boarding?" section.

Comment: @jcaron No both are different tickets, booked separately. I'm Pakistani. I have KSA multiple entry visit visa already. I only have to go to T2 from T3 to catch next flight. With Only hand bag

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178097/riyadh-airport-terminal-4-to-2) (which is about T4 -> T2) seem to say it's not possible get from T3 to T2 airside (only between T3 and T4). Not sure if that's still true.

Comment: Yes mate I already checked both threads but still dont have the perfect answer because of a bit specific query