# Do I need a visa if I am travelling from London to India, but plan to book a ticket with a layover in Bucharest and Riyadh?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, self-transfer

I am an Indian citizen travelling from London to India and I am planning to book a ticket with a self transfer at Bucharest and Riyadh. I only have one cabin bag. Do I need a visa for the self transfer?

Comment: Are you an Indian citizen?

Comment: Yes I am. I am in uk on student visa

Comment: Its much headache and probably expensive than a connection made by airline to arrange the visas.

Comment: For self-transfer bookings, you need to fulfil the entry requirement for the destination of each ticket (PNR), whether that entails getting a visa or being eligible for visa on arrival or visa-free entry. So you need to fulfil the entry requirements for Romania and Saudi Arabia to be allowed boarding.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer/171372#171372

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are an Indian citizen :

---

> > Romania - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a "D" visa issued by Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus or a
> Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 90 days. TWOV (Transit
> Without Visa)
>
> Passengers transiting through Bucharest (OTP), Cluj-Napoca (CLJ),
> Sibiu (SBZ) or Iasi (IAS) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight
> to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
> international transit area of the airport and have documents required
> for the next destination.

---

> > Saudi Arabia - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions
>
> First-degree family members of passengers with a 'Saudi Premium
> Residency' card. TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
>
> Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh
> (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country
> within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of
> the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.

---

As you are doing self tranfers, you will need both a [Saudi Transit Visa](https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474) **first** (if you don't get it first, your Romanian visa will be denied :

> > 2. Supporting documents to get a B-type visa:
>
> visa issued by the state of destination;

and then get a Romanian [B](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/30326) visa, to be applied on the [Romanian visa platform](https://eviza.mae.ro/)

Comment: OP mentions that he has only hand luggage. Wouldn't he be able to stay in the transit area in that case, hence be exempt from getting visa?

Comment: It will depend on if they can check in online, if they can't, they will for sure need a visa

Comment: I guess you checked Timatic for transit, but you must check it for destination since they are both self-transfers and each airline will most likely consider the next connection to be the final destination (especially if it is a low-cost airline). This makes transit through OTP require a visa, and transit through RUH not require one (visa on arrival, as OP has a UK visa).

Comment: @jcaron Saudi VOA is only for tourist and business visa, not for a student visa hodlder

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Ah indeed. So two visas required.

Comment: @Sabine They might, but typically for self-transfer as far as each airline is concerned the *final* destination is the one to which they are transporting the passenger, so they may well deny boarding.