# Do I need a transit visa if I'm flying through Abu Dhabi Airport with Wizz Air?

Tags: transit-visas, wizz-air, abu-dhabi

I am an Indian citizen and I have a resident permit in the Schengen Area. I am traveling to Abu Dhabi Airport soon. I am arriving on Air India and departing on WizzAir Abu Dhabi 5W7043. I have a 13 hour layover, and have purchased two separate tickets. I am unsure if I need to leave the airport or not. I have had a bad experience in the past where I was unable to leave the airport due to not having a visa, so I want to make sure I get one in advance, but I don't know where to apply for it.

The last time I had a similar issue, the airport officials told me I could apply for a transit visa 8 hours before my flight for free, but I only had 2 hours to spare. I had to book an Etihad airlines ticket quickly and didn't have time to apply for a visa. This time, I can't find the website where I can apply for a transit visa.

---

I think I need Transit visa because WizzAir leaves from Terminal 1 in Abu Dhabi.

---

I have found a website ([www.instadubai.ae](http://www.instadubai.ae)) that claims to offer Transit Visas, but their prices are expensive and they have a very poor reputation. Many reviews say that people paid them but never got a Visa.

Comment: Booking two separate tickets (two PNRs) can often mean a transit visa becomes necessary https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer You can check whether you need a transit visa by entering your full itinerary, residency, passport etc details here https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Comment: I think Transit VISA is required because Wizz leaves from terminal 1. I have previously encountered this problem with another airlines that also leaves from Terminal 1. But I bought the return ticket together and it is not refundable. Otherwise I wouldn't have gone through the same situation.