# Do you have to go through border control at Heathrow if you have an overnight layover at the same terminal?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, lhr

If someone lands at LHR from Canada at 9pm, and have a departing flight in the morning, can they stay airside and avoid going through border control. Does this change if the flights are on one ticket or two separate tickets?

If one does have to go through border control and cannot stay airside overnight, what does one do if they are barred from entry to the UK but are just transiting through?

Comment: I'm not sure about the UK, but in many countries if you're barred from entry you also cannot transit there.

Comment: @AndrewRay, it is often possible to transfer by staying in the international area, and those people often do not need a visa. But on the other hand, often there are limits on how long you can stay and if the terminal is closed overnight the limits stop you to stay in the night.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, in general, but in some countries being excluded also means you lose the privilege of transferring without a visa.

Comment: An entry ban is an entry ban, AFAIK there is no exemption allowing someone to transit landside. For transiting on two separate tickets, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer

Comment: Input your self-transfer details into this tool https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y and after the list of exemptions for TWOV there’s a section that says *” You will not be able to transit without a visa if a Border Force officer decides you do not qualify under the immigration rules.”*

Comment: Regarding your last question, "If one does have to go through border control and cannot stay airside overnight, what does one do if they are barred from entry to the UK but are just transiting through?", most likely the answer is "they are denied boarding in Canada" and have thrown away the price of their air ticket. But worse options are possible.