# TWOV-UK / Irish stamp 1/ Indian national

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens

Indian National with Stamp 1 Irish visa. Can I transit landside without visa in UK on my way to Ireland. Would I be a covered under the exception- be travelling to the Republic of Ireland and have a valid biometric visa. However there is no mention of BC or BC BIVS in the residence card or stamp. Please advise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transit without Visa-UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182036/transit-without-visa-uk)

Comment: You asked this question already. The answer won't change by asking it again.

Comment: Sorry I thought the conditions are different on way to Ireland instead of from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Judging by your previous question [Transit without Visa-UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182036/transit-without-visa-uk) you have a biometric Irish Residence Permit (IRP).

To be granted permission to enter the UK as a Transit Visitor under the [Transit Without Visa Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-transit-without-visa-scheme) a visa national must meet all the requirements at TWOV 2. and one of the requirements at TWOV 3.

You qualify under TWOV 2. but you do **not** qualify under TWOV 3. An IRP is not an *Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section)*.

Comment: They **do** qualify under TWOV 3 (h), *hold a valid common format residence permit issued by an EEA state (pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No. 1030/2002) or Switzerland*

Comment: @NicolasFormichella No, from the previous question (with accepted answer)  the OP does not have a common format residence permit.

Comment: @Traveller all clear.. sorry I thought maybe the conditions are different on the way to Ireland instead of from Ireland

Comment: @Traveller I have a valid US visa but need a ticket to US to avail the TWOV.. there’s a loophole though here.. a ticket can be reserved for US and since there are no exit checks, they don’t check whether person is indeed going to US or any other country after landside entry

Comment: @GauravTaparia Not sure if that is an option, the airline would likely check your reservation for US is legit before allowing you to board. You have a Schengen visa, why not transit in eg Amsterdam or Paris?

Comment: @Traveller One can book legit reservations which are verifiable for few dollars. Transit in other European countries are not the cheapest