# Do Green Card holders need a visa for UK transit?

Tags: usa, uk, transit-visas

I am a Turkish citizen holding a Green Card and living in the United States. I will be traveling from Orlando to Gatwick Airport, and from there, I will be heading to Turkey. I will have my immigrant visa stamped passport and Green Card with me. Do I need to obtain a transit visa for the 2-hour layover in the UK?

I have purchased a self-transfer ticket, and I've already checked in for the London to Istanbul leg of my journey. However, I need to go to the check-in area to have my documents verified. I'm feeling a bit anxious because I'll be traveling with different airlines.
Furthermore, I will be traveling with just my backpack, so there will be no need for me to go to the baggage claim area.

Edit:
Hello friends, I successfully completed the flight today without any issues, thanks to God. The main reasons were having my boarding pass ready for the flight and having my green card, of course. I hope it helps someone who reads this, and I'm grateful to everyone who responded.

Comment: Will you stay airside, or will you have to pass through passport control? As far as I understand the rules, your Green Card gives you Airside Transit Visa exemption, but that's it. If you have to pass through passport control, you'll need a landside transit visa.

Comment: I will be going to Wizz Air for document control, so I think I will have to go through passport control. But when i check the gov.uk I am eligible for these two privileges: you have a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998 you have a valid USA I-551 Temporary Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp version will not be accepted)

Comment: @mlc It answers my question, according to the website, a green card is sufficient, but in Turkish forums it is insistently written that it requires a connecting flight. For this reason, I insistently try to get information from everyone.

Comment: There are currently (Oct 2023) no Airside transfer facilities at Gatwick Airport. They were closed during Covid and have not re-opened. (Source - work at Gatwick airport).

Comment: @dda a green card also grants exemption from the requirement to have a visitor in transit visa.  See https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/turkey/transit/somewhere_else/yes

Comment: @canonacer but green card holders (among others) do not require airside transit facilities to make this transit without a visa.

Comment: See [this summary](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/6527ca22244f8e00138e74b2/UK_Visa_requirements_October_2023_.pdf)

Comment: @Zeustira See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171352/do-i-always-need-to-go-through-immigration-if-i-have-a-self-transfer) for some very good reasons why self-transfer may be problematic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: @phoog. I was just spreading the word about the current lack of airside transit facilities at Gatwick in case anyone else was interested/affected.

Comment: @Zeustira thanks for coming back to let us know what happened.  You can post this information as an answer to your own question; see [Can I answer my own question?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in [Help](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 6):

As you've noticed, UK law does not require you to have a transit visa (https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/turkey/transit/somewhere_else/yes).

> I'm feeling a bit anxious because I'll be traveling with different airlines.

This is indeed the source of your potential problem.  The first airline may be overly cautious and refuse to accept your assertion that you have "a confirmed onward flight" and they may refuse to let you on the plane.

Even if they believe the flight is for real, they may ask themselves what will happen if their flight is delayed by two hours or more, which is not at all uncommon.  If that happens you will no longer meet the criteria for the visa exemption.  Will the airline be fined in that case?  They probably know better than I.

(You should also be prepared for the possibility of having to buy a same-day or next-day ticket from London to Turkey in the not-unlikely event that you miss your WizzAir flight.)

I suspect that these considerations explain what you've read in Turkish forums about connecting flights.  Surely at least sometimes people are denied boarding by certain airlines because of these considerations.  It's possible that some airlines would board self-transfer passengers in some circumstances, but clearly they wouldn't if the transfer time were, say, 20 minutes.  The longer the time, the more likely they'd accept the passenger, but two hours is somewhat on the short side.

If you can confirm with the first airline that they will board you in these circumstances, you should be fine.  If not, you should get a visa if you have time.

Comment: Assuming you have a ticket, why would an airline "refuse to accept your assertion that you have a confirmed onward flight"?

Comment: @DJClayworth the possibility that the ticket is forged, perhaps, though maybe they have independent means of verifying it; I do not know.  The possibility of missing the flight, on the other hand, seems a real problem, and I do not know how that works in practice.  Suppose the flight departs on time and arrives two or more hours late.  Is the airline fined?  Does it have to spend time and effort explaining why it shouldn't be?

Comment: I tried to reach out everywhere, including the British consulate in Turkey and the airport, but I couldn't get a real answer from anyone. Therefore, to prove that my seat ticket is real, I need to take a screenshot of my flight from Turkey to America dated November 9th and my invitation and explain that it is my sister's wedding and I have to get there. It's very sad because it's ridiculous that I have to deal with so much paperwork just because of the country I was born in. So i just have to be try and see fellas.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica I don't think that's the airline's concern -- they're only concerned about getting fined by the UK.  If the passenger complies with the criteria for the visa exemption then the airline should not be liable for a fine regardless of what happens -- just as airlines are not fined if they transport a tourist to the UK who has the right documents but never leaves.

Comment: Thanks, @phoog. On reflection, I think you're right. I was thinking of a supposed sterile transit, not a visa exemption transit. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @DJClayworth In the case of self-transit, for the first airline, the final destination is the UK, and they are quite entitled to ask for evidence the passenger can actually enter the destination country, not just transit, and this happens quite often. It is more likely if the transit conditions are very strict (e.g. stay airside, or limited to a few hours), and less likely when they are less strict (passenger allowed to go through passport control and stay several days). In this case, passenger is allowed to go landsite and must leave before midnight the next day, so that leaves some margin.

Comment: @DJClayworth I also think traditional airlines doing a lot of long-haul are more likely to accept this than low-cost airlines, but it could also be just pure luck.

Comment: @phoog this guidance for airlines (P10 onwards) states a fine is issued based on whether the documentation is inadequate, not on whether they leave on time. It further warns airlines that if the passenger is denied boarding in the UK for travel to the 3rd country they may be fined (so the warning that airlines will be extra wary when the itinerary is split is correct) https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1127332/Charging_procedures_A_guide_for_Carriers.pdf

Comment: @MJeffryes it actually says that they may be charged if the passenger is denied boarding for onward travel "because of the detection of an inadequacy in documentation," which wouldn't apply in this case (nor if the passenger were denied for some other reason).